# Solve implicit conversion loses integer precision target warning in iOS

Tags: c, ios10, xcode8, implicit-conversion

I rather drag this warning than screwing up deploying a wrong conversion.
In this line XCode8 (Swift3, iOS10) .c file :

```
SHA1Update(&theSHA1Context, (size_t)inText, inTextLength);
//void SHA1Update(SHA1_CTX* context, u_int8_t* data, unsigned int len)
```

I am getting this warning

```
"Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'size_t' to 'u_int32_t' (aka 'unsigned_int')
```

I am no expert in this field, so I rather take savvy advice, what is the best way to satisfy XCode and take out that warning?

Comment: Don't use casts unless you know all implications and accept them! Said that: what is the signature of `SHA1Update`?

Comment: What is a Swift 3 .c file? Swift and C are different languages.

Comment: Obviously yes. However XCode complains in a different way depending on the Swift setting of the project, even if it has Objective C or C code in it. I you were migrating you would be aware of that. @MartinR

Answer (score 0):

If the variable names are anything to go by, that was mis-cast:

```
SHA1Update(&theSHA1Context, inText, inTextLength);
```

Comment: @Josh OK, I think you can get away with no casts at all.

Comment: If you can't get away with no casts to avoid the warning, it looks like you'd need to use `(unsigned int)inTextLength`.

Answer (score 0):

2 issues

1. The length field is expected to be `unsigned`, which is narrower than `size_t` on your platform - hence the warning.  To narrow a value, use a cast and quiet the warning.  But casting can cause catastrophic problems if the target is not representable.  Suggest using a test.

   ```
   //void SHA1Update(SHA1_CTX* context, u_int8_t* data, unsigned int len)
   //                                narrowing -----v
   // SHA1Update(&theSHA1Context, (size_t)inText, inTextLength);

   size_t inTextLength;
   assert(inTextLength <= UINT_MAX);
   SHA1Update(&theSHA1Context, (size_t)inText, (unsigned) inTextLength);
   ```
2. The casing of the buffer `inText` is certainly an error.  Remove it.

   ```
   SHA1Update(&theSHA1Context, inText, (unsigned) inTextLength);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

After trying suggestions, this changes satisfied the compiler, and OAuth continued to work properly:

```
    //old code:
    //SHA1Update(&theSHA1Context, (u_int8_t *)inText, inTextLength); 

    //new code:
    SHA1Update(&theSHA1Context, (unsigned char *)inText, (unsigned int)inTextLength);
```